# paypal DoExpressCheckoutPayment method

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to build a very simple paypal-backed shopping cart so users can purchase multiple items.For that i have some doubts regarding DoExpressCheckoutPayment method.

What will happen if won't call this method, Lets take a scenario customer has paid from paypal site but i have not called DoExpressCheckoutPayment method of paypal, Do they deduct the money from customer account if i will not call DoExpressCheckoutPayment method ?

Does any one know what will happen in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No money is transferred until the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call is made successfully.  That is the call that actually processes the funds.

Comment: PayPal employee here -- and I can confirm that Andrew is correct.